# Java JAR file dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a question on `jar` file.

Let say I have a `a.jar`, which has dependencies on `b.jar` and `c.jar`.

Many articles I read is that when we want to export the `a.jar` to let say another project, `a.jar` won't work because its dependencies will not be referenced namely here `b.jar` and `c.jar`.

But what if we deliver not just `a.jar` but also `b.jar` and `c.jar` altogether in this another project? Would this solve the issue?

My guess is that I am wrong here - if it were so easy, a lot of people would be doing it and there would be no articles about this issue.

So, I came up with an idea. If it sounds funny, please correct me.

What if I re-work my `a.jar` to several `jar`s among which no-one depends on each other and "zip" these up as a whole `jar` file?

In addition, I am thinking why `rt.jar` would not have the dependency issue.

Comment: One basic problem is that if you ship b.jar and c.jar then you may be shipping versions that are different from those already on the client box.  In the worst case you get an uplevel b.jar and downlevel c.jar and end up in NoClassDefFoundError hell.

Answer (score 1):

> if it were so easy, a lot of people would be doing it and there would be no articles about this issue.

Ironically, that's almost that easy as you expected.  For some predefined J2EE artifacts (WAR, EAR etc), that's the way it is done: dependencies are bundled in an archive.

The reason that there are similar problem is, there is no standard way to perform such bundling for ordinary Java applications, and there are difficulties in finding out dependencies transitively without aid of tools.  In brief, if you can bundle `a.jar, b.jar, c.jar` in a zip, and have a script that will put `b.jar` and `c.jar` in classpath, and then execute `a.jar`, then everything is going to be fine.

Way to solve the transitive dependencies is normally by the build tools.  Maven, Ant+Ivy, Gradle etc are all good in dealing with this.

Then it comes to bundling.  There are normally 2 ways dealing with it.

First is by creating a bundle with corresponding scripts.  In the zip file it contains all the dependency JARs, and possibly script to do the classpath setup + execution.  Maven AppAssembler plugin is one of the example

Second way is to create an Uber JAR which contains contents of all dependencies in the single JAR itself.  It is probably easiest in deployment.  You can easily do it by Maven Shade plugin or Maven Assemly plugin.

(There are other way like putting dependency reference in the JAR manifest etc but personally I think the above 2 are more widely used and easier to adopt)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

**Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Here is an excerpt:

```
You may need to reference classes in other JAR files from within a JAR file.

For example, in a typical situation an applet is bundled in a JAR file whose 
manifest references a different JAR file (or several different JAR files) that 
serves as utilities for the purposes of that applet.

You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the manifest 
file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes the following form:

Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name


By using the Class-Path header in the manifest, you can avoid having to 
specify a long -classpath flag when invoking Java to run the your application.
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an "uber jar" which contains your classes and dependencies in a single jar at the same level.  For example, if `a.jar` contains `com.foo.MyClass` and depends on `com.b.ThirdPartyClass` in `b.jar`, then the uber jar would contain both `com.foo.MyClass` and `com.b.ThirdPartyClass`.

One could of course do this manually, although it would be a bit tedious.  However, I'd recommend something like Maven's Shade plugin or its UberJar plugin.  These tools will rename classes in different jars that happen to have names that would cause a conflict, such as a.jar and b.jar both having class `util.StringUtils`.

There are also non-Maven solutions.  A search for "uber jar" or "jar or jars" (even though that's not what you really want" should turn up some tools.

Re `rt.jar`, that ships with the JRE, so you do not have to include that in your release.

Answer (score 0):

All these kind of jar dependencies can be taken care by simple maven or gradle dependency management systems.
Try it out